# list with checkBoxes in a navigation drawer

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, navigation-drawer

Im trying to make a navigation drawer with a listview that has check boxes in it. as each list item. this is what i have tried so far , But im having great difficulty.

what im looking to is create a prefence menu.
i.e "bluetooth on/off (checkbox)" etc

Heres My Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

//Navigation Drawer Member Variables
private ListView mDrawerList;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private String mActivityTitle;

//Navigation Drawer

    mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();

    addDrawerItems();
    setupDrawer();

 private void addDrawerItems() {
    String[] osArray = { "Bluetooth", "Reply to Calls", "Reply to sms", "customise message"};
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, osArray);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView)view;
            if (ctv.isChecked()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"uncheckd",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"checked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
}



    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}
```

Im getting an error saying that the adapter needs a text view. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hi, can you share the complete code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is beacuse you have to pass a TextView instead of R.layout.list_item, check the below example:

```
 mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.my_textview, osArray);
```

To create a **ListView** with checkboxes set the ChoiceMode to "CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE"

```
    String[] osArray = {"Bluetooth", "Reply to Calls", "Reply to sms", "customise message"};
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, osArray);

    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you so very much!! :) it took me a week :( to get this far, im sorry to and a bit embarrassed to say. How could I have it so that when you you tap the words bluetooth or anywhere else on the bluetooth row that it will open Alert dialog and not change the state of the check box, but with the other rows beneath i.e "calls"& "sms" you can click the checkbox or anywhere on that row to change the state of the check box.

Comment: Hi can you give me a complete code how to add check boxes to list view?

Comment: Hi just add this listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE); to your listview, thats all

Comment: Can you answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37044562/error-while-adding-check-boxes-to-navigation-drawer ? i'm stuck here. :(