# Error while adding Check boxes to Navigation Drawer ListView

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add a customized navigation drawer to my android application. What i need is to add a list view containing icon, name and a check box.

Currently, i was able to add an icon and name.

This is my `onCreateView` in `NavigationDrawerFragment.java`

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });

        final TypedArray typedArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.sections_icons);
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sections)
        ) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                int resourceId = typedArray.getResourceId(position, 0);
                Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(resourceId);
                ((TextView) v).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null, null);
                return v;
            }
        });

        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return mDrawerListView;
    }
```

But, I couldn't add check box to my navigation drawer.
So, I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36187963/list-with-checkboxes-in-a-navigation-drawer) and I tried to add check box by adding `mDrawerList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);`

This gives me the following error.

```
05-05 11:24:49.537    3640-3640/com.myayubo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myayubo, PID: 3640
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myayubo/com.myayubo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.myayubo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:67)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Someone please tell me how to add check boxes to my code.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this way:

```
@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);

   ListView mDrawerListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
   mDrawerList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    // Other stuff
   return rootView; 
 }
```

**Edit 1:**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);

   ListView mDrawerListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
   mDrawerList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });

        final TypedArray typedArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.sections_icons);
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sections)
        ) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                int resourceId = typedArray.getResourceId(position, 0);
                Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(resourceId);
                ((TextView) v).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null, null);
                return v;
            }
        });

        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return rootView;
    }
```

You are doing wrong with Binding of ListView.

Hope this will make sense.

Comment: You mean I need to remove other code inside onCreateView and add this?

Comment: @QualityProducts, you should bind listview like my code

Comment: I'm really sorry for ask this question. I don't understand it since I'm new to android. Can u be more descriptive? Can u get my answer and edit it? Thanks. :)

Comment: @QualityProducts, I have edited my answer with Edit 1.

Comment: Hi, added ur code and then it gives an error saying cannot find symbol isDrawerOpen()

Comment: @QualityProducts, make sure mDrawerListView object must not null

Comment: Hi, Sry DrawerListView object must not null error came because of my fault. Now, code is running. But, I don't get text boxes in my drawer yet. :(

Comment: It gives the same error in the line mDrawerList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE); :(

Comment: Added the mDrawerList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);  to NavigationDrawerFragment not to the MainActivity. Problem solved. :)